# R question. 'scatterplot' function in 'car' library. "object is not a matrix" error

Tags: r

Any ideas why I am getting an error with the following code?

Thanks in advance!

```
library(lattice)
library(car)

set.seed(1234)
response=round(rnorm(60),2)
explanatory<-round(c(rnorm(20, 10,1), rnorm(10, 8, 1), rnorm(10,20,1), rnorm(20,18,1)),2)
gender=c(rep("male", 30), rep("female", 30))
factor1=as.factor(c(rep('a', 20), rep('b', 20), rep('c', 20)))
scatterplot(response~explanatory, smooth=FALSE, reg.line=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `scatterplot` is intended to use with data frames, check:

```
df <- data.frame(response, explanatory)
scatterplot(response~explanatory, df, smooth=FALSE, reg.line=FALSE)
```

Output:

[image: result image with scatterplot]

I have no idea what you want to do with *gender* and *factor1*.

Comment: Bingo!  I had those vectors in a data frame but I wasn't using the data frame as an argument for the scatterplot() function.  I am going to plot according to 'gender' and 'factor1'

Comment: This code runs though. Terribly sorry about the formatting.  `require(Sleuth2)
require(MASS)
require(calibrate)
require(lattice)
library(car)



attach(ex0918)

Wing.Size<-c(Females, Males)

Gender<-as.factor(c(rep("Female", length(Females)), rep("Male", length(Males))))

continent<-as.factor(c(rep(c(rep("NA", 11), rep("EU", 10)
          ),2
        ) 
      )
     ) 
latitude2<-c(rep(Latitude,2))

Gender.continent=as.factor(paste(Gender, continent))

type<-as.numeric(Gender.continent)
      
scatterplot(Wing.Size ~ latitude2|Gender.continent, smooth=FALSE, reg.line=FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

```
scatterplot(cbind(response, explanatory), smooth=FALSE, reg.line=FALSE)
```

Is this what you were looking for? The error was telling, it said not a matrix because what you provided wasn't.

[image]

Looks like gender and factor1 have nothing to do with your issue. Not sure I understand why the code was included

Comment: My goal ultimately is to plot those according to 'gender' and 'factor1' which I have done previously by pasting those two factors as a new variable (gender.factor1) and then 'scatterplot(response~explanatory|gender.factor1, smooth=FALSE, reg.line=FALSE)'     That does not seem to be working on this code though and I'm not sure why.